# jquery function in my javascript file doesn't get called

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I have a javascript file which has a jquery function in a javascript file under the Scripts folder. The function listens to drop down click event and fills the textbox with the selected value like below, but when I click the drop down option, this method doesn't get called and the value is not set in the text box. When I run with debugger (F12), if I paste the function in the debugger command line then clicking the drop down works!!!! Not sure why the method is not registered from the javascript file. The dropdown-menu and input text box are created using bootstrap input-group. The drop down is initially empty and filled by reading from a file in setup() function.

```
// In test.js
var testMap = {}

$(function () {
    $("#dropdownlistId li a").click(function () {
        var name = $(this).text();
        $("#textBoxId").val(name);
    });
});

function setup() {
    // Read name and value pair in testMap
    ...
    // Append names to drop down list
    $.each(testMap, function (key, value) {
            $("#dropdownlistId").append("<li> <a tabindex=\"-1\" href=\"#\"> " + key + "</a>  </li>");
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    setup();
});
```

In my cshtml file, I am calling the javascript file like:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/test.js") 
}

<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="textBoxId" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name" />
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul id="dropdownlistId" class="dropdown-menu pull-right"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What function isn't being called? `$("#dropdownlistId li a").click()`? Is your javascript file (test.js) getting loaded? When you view your developer tools, does the file showup in the dropdown of the "Script" tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running into an issue where you're trying to bind to elements that do not yet exist. The `ul#dropdownlistId` exists statically in the page template, but the `li`'s and their children are populated  after the DOM Ready (via your setup function). You can change the binding to be bound to the element that always exists (`ul#dropdownlistId`) and only act on certain child elements (`li a`):

```
$(function () {
    $('#dropdownlistId').on('click', 'li a', function () {
        $('#textBoxId').val($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: That's exactly the problem: the binding happens before the elements are actually present on the page.

Comment: Right, that was it. So does this mean that the jquery methods are bound to DOM elements at compile time?

Comment: The binding still occurs at DOM Ready, but it essentially makes it so you don't have to bind to each child individually.